# Map url to Controller (and methods if possible) by name in Spring along with @Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In ASP.NET there's UrlHelper which maps url to controller and method based on their respectives names, for example: `/perform/dance` URL maps to `PerformController`'s `dance` method.

I know this is possible in spring by using "ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" but it requires the controller class to extend `absctractController` or `MultiActionController`, I want to have only my class annotated with `@Controller` and have the URL mapped to it by its name and the same for its methods.

I want to have a consistency in my code without having to manually type a `@RequestMapping("theMethodName")` annotation.

Is there a way to have URLs mapped to Controllers and its methods based on their respective names?

What I'm trying to achieve:

```
@Controller
public class PerformController{

public string dance(){
//do something
}
}
```

access dance method through `/perform/dance`

as opposed to:

```
     @Controller
     @RequestMapping("/perform")
        public class PerformController{

        @RequestMapping(value="/dance")
        public string dance(){
        //do something
        }
    }
```

(An example would be pretty much appreciated.)

Comment: With annotations you cannot, without you can as you already stated. So don't use annotations is basically the answer.

Comment: Please add some paragraphs!

Comment: check my edited question.